# Why is this incrementer returning NAN when if I hard code the index it works as expected?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple factorial code challenge, but with Javascript, when I try to get the index position by looping of the indexes, I get NAN.  I understand that NAN is of the typeOf number, just that Javascript doesn't know which number.  I don't see why that is happening in this case.  Also how can I use get the index of an array by looping over them in Javascript?  Thanks!

```
// Input = 4 Output = 24
// Input = 8 Output = 40320

var total = 0;
var factor_Array = [];
function FirstFactorial(num) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    factor_Array.unshift(i);
    // console.log(factor_Array);
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < factor_Array.length; j++){
    // Why does this work??? But not when I use 'j' to grab the index    position?  Seems like BOTH ways should work
    total = factor_Array[0] * factor_Array[0+1];
    total = factor_Array[j] * factor_Array[j+1];

  }
 console.log(total);
 //return num;

}
FirstFactorial(4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when `j = (factor_Array.length-1)` it tries to access the j+1 element, which doesn't exist.

The following would work as you expect

```
for (var j = 0; j < (factor_Array.length-1); j++){
    total = factor_Array[j] * factor_Array[j+1];
}
```

Comment: in the last iteration of the second loop the program will fail.
when j = factor_array.length - 1 there is no j+1 element in the array...

Comment: It won't fail. Accessing a non-existant index of an array returns `undefined`, and `Number` times `undefined` is `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense now :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you loop

```
for (var j = 0; j < factor_Array.length; j++){
    total = factor_Array[j] * factor_Array[j+1];
}
```

Then then on the last iteration you will be out of the array bounds since

```
j = factor_Array.length - 1
```

and you're accessing `j + 1`.